# receiving signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS in web service call function

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.2

I'm new to iPhone development. I'm using xcode 4.2.

When I click on the save button, I'm getting values from the html page and my web service is processing them, and then I get the error:

> program received signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

in my web service call function. Here is my code:

```
     NSString *val=[WebviewObj stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"save()"];
    NSLog(@"return value:: %@",val);
    [adict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",userid5] forKey:@"iUser_Id" ];
    [adict setObject:[[val componentsSeparatedByString:@","]objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"vImage_Url"];
    [adict setObject:[[val componentsSeparatedByString:@","]objectAtIndex:1] forKey:@"IGenre_Id"];
    [adict setObject:[[val componentsSeparatedByString:@","]objectAtIndex:2] forKey:@"vTrack_Name"];
    [adict setObject:[[val componentsSeparatedByString:@","]objectAtIndex:3] forKey:@"vAlbum_Name"];
    [adict setObject:[[val componentsSeparatedByString:@","]objectAtIndex:4] forKey:@"vMusic_Url"];
    [adict setObject:[[val componentsSeparatedByString:@","]objectAtIndex:5] forKey:@"iTrack_Duration_min"];
    [adict setObject:[[val componentsSeparatedByString:@","]objectAtIndex:6] forKey:@"iTrack_Duration_sec"];
    [adict setObject:[[val componentsSeparatedByString:@","]objectAtIndex:7] forKey:@"vDescription"];
    NSLog(@"dict==%@",[adict description]);

  NSString *URL2= @"http://184.164.156.55/Music/Track.asmx/AddTrack";
  obj=[[UrlController alloc]init];
  obj.URL=URL2;
  obj.InputParameters = adict;
  [obj WebserviceCall];
 obj.delegate= self;

       //this is my function..it is working for so many function calls
     -(void)WebserviceCall{


     webData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

  NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[ NSMutableURLRequest alloc ] initWithURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: URL ] ];

   NSString *httpBody = @"";
        for(id key in InputParameters)
        {
         if([httpBody length] == 0){
         httpBody=[httpBody stringByAppendingFormat:@"&%@=%@",key,[InputParameters valueForKey:key]];
    }
         else{
         httpBody=[httpBody stringByAppendingFormat:@"&%@=%@",key,[InputParameters valueForKey:key]];
          }
          }
       httpBody = [httpBody stringByAppendingFormat:httpBody];//Here i am getting  EXC_BAD_ACCESS 

        [urlRequest setHTTPMethod: @"POST" ];
     [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[httpBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
     [urlRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];


          NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];



       }
```

Can any one help me please?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`stringByAppendingFormat` expects a (sprintf-style) formatting string as its first argument, then one more argument for each % format placeholder. For example:

```
[httpBody stringByAppendingFormat:@"Integer: %d, String: %@", 1234, @"Hello"];
```

If your `httpBody` string happens to contain a '%' followed by a valid format type (e.g. 'd', 'f', '@', etc.), then `stringByAppendingFormat` will expect extra arguments, which you aren't supplying. Attempting to dereference those arguments will cause your EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

I haven't followed your code's logic right through, so I'm not sure what you actually intended on that line.